# Picasa API photo URL expiration

Tags: google-api, picasa

We use Picasa Google API with OAuth 2.0. Session token expires after one hour. During this hour we retrieve a user photo and get its content URL from the media:group (this is the URL of the image itself).

We see that this URL still works though session has expired. Does this URL ever expire?

The URL looks like:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-iXvyLB_PnyA/UdAiPE-W7qI/AAAAAAAOo0/nNnqspBaxGc/s3000/IMG_1.JPG

Answer (score 0):

Picasa pictures do expire. I have lost pictures take 3 years ago. Do not store pictures on Picasa as a backup for Picasa will roll them off into cyper space. I do not at what time frame Picasa has elected to roll pictures off.